# Printing from Ubuntu through SBS 2003 server

Tags: ubuntu, network-printer, cups

I am having problems printing to the printer connected to my (SBS2003) business's network.

I know the IP of the printer and I can ping it and even print files from it by going to 192.168.0.50 in firefox and uploading a file.

If I do an `nmap` on the IP of the printer I get this:

```
jamesmaddison@development:~$ nmap 192.168.0.50

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-11 16:12 BST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.50
Host is up (0.46s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
23/tcp    open  telnet
80/tcp    open  http
443/tcp   open  https
515/tcp   open  printer
631/tcp   open  ipp
5900/tcp  open  vnc
9100/tcp  open  jetdirect
50001/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.55 seconds
```

I can't get my local cups server to print to it no matter what protocol I use. I am in the business workgroup and the printer even lists my computer in the workgroup.

The Printer is a Sharp MX-M314N. All Windows computers on the network can print to it fine, just my ubuntu machine that won't.

Here's what the CUPS error log says for the last job I tried.

```
E [11/Jul/2013:16:21:28 +0100] [cups-polld MASTERMAGNETS:631] Unable to connect to MASTERMAGNETS on port 631.
```

Here's what `nmap` reports when I run it on the SBS

```
jamesmaddison@development:~$ nmap mastermagnets

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-11 16:35 BST
Nmap scan report for mastermagnets (192.168.0.2)
Host is up (0.00055s latency).
rDNS record for 192.168.0.2: mastermagnets.local
Not shown: 957 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
25/tcp    open  smtp
42/tcp    open  nameserver
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
88/tcp    open  kerberos-sec
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
389/tcp   open  ldap
443/tcp   open  https
444/tcp   open  snpp
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
464/tcp   open  kpasswd5
593/tcp   open  http-rpc-epmap
636/tcp   open  ldapssl
691/tcp   open  resvc
1025/tcp  open  NFS-or-IIS
1027/tcp  open  IIS
1042/tcp  open  unknown
1045/tcp  open  unknown
1046/tcp  open  unknown
1048/tcp  open  unknown
1049/tcp  open  unknown
1054/tcp  open  unknown
1081/tcp  open  unknown
1087/tcp  open  unknown
1094/tcp  open  unknown
1104/tcp  open  unknown
2301/tcp  open  compaqdiag
2381/tcp  open  unknown
3268/tcp  open  globalcatLDAP
3269/tcp  open  globalcatLDAPssl
3389/tcp  open  ms-term-serv
5633/tcp  open  unknown
6001/tcp  open  X11:1
6002/tcp  open  X11:2
6004/tcp  open  X11:4
6101/tcp  open  backupexec
6106/tcp  open  isdninfo
8080/tcp  open  http-proxy
8081/tcp  open  blackice-icecap
8082/tcp  open  blackice-alerts
8443/tcp  open  https-alt
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.18 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print to your Windows server (192.168.0.2). Just print to the network printer(192.168.0.50) directly.

Comment: CUPS is setup to print to socket://192.168.0.50:9100 though.